# Most popular collocations

Tags: java, erlang, mapreduce, data-mining, text-extraction

Could anyone help to find most popular N collocations in set of K files. 
I've already implemented basic Map Reduce for finding most popular words (word counter). But how can I deal with collocations ? Any snippets will be appreciated (Erlang, Python, Java, C++).

For simplicity, assume that collocation is an expression with two words. For example "beautiful girl", "dark passenger".

Comment: Can't you do exactly what you're already doing, but operate on pairs of consecutive words instead of individual words?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Ok, I have done Map Reduce on Erlang Machine and use Mongo as data-storage. Mongo collection contains a lot of different text files. What I would like to do is to show most important collocations in those files.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in one map-reduce job? It seems unlikely. Also what technique are you using to find collocations?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the idea is just the same as with word counts but you have to store previous word somewhere for each of your map operation. Or you can fill collection with pairs of words and use the same operation as for simple words.

So, we have text that consists of sentences and each sentence consist of words. If collocation is a couple of successive words inside a sentence then the code would probably look like this:

```
calc(Text) ->
   calc(undefined, [], Text, dict:new()).

calc(W1, [W2 | Sentence], Text, Dict) ->
   NewDict = dict:update_counter({W1, W2}, -1, Dict),
   calc(W2, Sentence, Text, NewDict);
calc(_, [], [[Word | Sentence] | Text], Dict) ->
   calc(Word, Sentence, Text, Dict);
calc(_, _, [], Dict) ->
   List = dict:to_list(Dict),
   Sorted = lists:keysort(2, List),
   {Result, _} = lists:split(50, Sorted),
   [{Key, -Value} || Value <- Result].
```

Of course you need to make sure you have enough memory for this method because it makes many copies of data in the end.